# how can I run tests on codemagic for native ios app?

Tags: ios, xcode, yaml, codemagic

I am trying to build a CI/CD flow for my app, but I got a problem with the yaml.
I am not getting a good response of codemagic, this is the error:
[image: error]

I have a target in my project named PortfolioTests and my yaml code is this one:

```
workflows:
 develop:

instance_type: mac_mini_m1
environment:
  xcode: 14.2
  vars:
    #BUNDLE_ID: "io.codemagic.sample.iosnative"
    XCODE_WORKSPACE: "Portfolio.xcodeproj" # <-- Name of your Xcode workspace
    XCODE_SCHEME: "PortfolioTests" # <-- Name of your Xcode scheme

scripts:
  - name: say hello
    script: echo "Hello Codemagician!"
    
    
  - name: Run iOS tests
    script: |
      set -e # exit on first failed command

      xcode-project run-tests \
          --workspace ${XCODE_WORKSPACE?} \
          --scheme ${XCODE_SCHEME?} \
          --device "iPhone 12"
    #test_report: build/ios/test/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your command to

```
xcode-project run-tests \
          --project ${XCODE_WORKSPACE?} \
          --scheme ${XCODE_SCHEME?} \
          --device "iPhone 12"
```

instead? As it is a project and not a workspace.